# How to make wet fries?

Tags: sauce, chips

There's a place that does 'wet fries.' They look more like English chips though, and they're basically floppy and wet from the sauce it's placed into.

The ingredients, as told by the manager, are:

- Sweet chilli sauce
- Hot chilli sauce
- Tomato sauce
- Garlic
- Sesame Oil

As far as ratios go, do you believe there should be more of one particular sauce than the other? I wouldn't want to put in way more of one thing than I need.

Comment: Other than the sesame oil, it actually sounds similar to sauces you might find for patatas bravas

Comment: It sounds and looks like regular fries smothered with gravy (where the gravy can be pretty much whatever you have on hand).

Answer (score 1):

See how it tastes without the garlic first.  The chili sauces often have garlic in themselves.

All of the other ingredients will obviously add more wetness, in their own separate ways.

To make the fries themselves wetter, use more oil while frying them, and/or leave them in the oil longer at a lower temperature. In this case absorbing more oil makes them "wetter", but I'm not sure if that is quite what you are going for?

Comment: More oil is going to make them greasy.  I'd actually recommend frying them normally, and just let them sit into the sauce until they're floppy enough.  You can always add more sauce if you want them soggier.

Comment: Right, more oil will make them greasier; that's why I said that would make them "wetter [in one sense], but I'm not sure if that is what you are going for".

Comment: @Jefromi multiple separate answers in this case made sense.
I'm not a noob to Stack in general (just cooking Stack); multiple answers is a supported acceptable style on Stack in general.
See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104966/197173 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139476/197173.
Now my separate answers about garlic and wetness are lumped together; not good as you can't tell which answer votes are for, and their conversation will be mixed together here...

Comment: @cellepo I don't have a citation offhand, but even on main meta I've seen clear advice against "one idea per answer" type things. In this case, your answers address two aspects of the question. They're not fundamentally different answers, they don't conflict, you don't have to pick one or the other. It's quite reasonable to have them together; it's very very common to have more than one idea in a single answer. In any case, I've been on cooking long enough to be fairly confident about this, but if you'd like to hear from others, feel free to post on our meta.